# Appending all values (each containing a list) of a dict to pandas df

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a column, with each row containing a python dictionary with multiple keys and values. Each value is a list. Index[0] looks like:

```
{'Paradigms': ['Agile Software Development',
  'Scrum',
  'DevOps',
  'Serverless Architecture'],
 'Platforms': ['Kubernetes',
  'Linux',
  'Windows',
  'Eclipse',
  'PagerDuty',
  'Apache2',
  'Docker',
  'AWS EC2',
  'Amazon Web Services (AWS)',
  'Sysdig',
  'Apache Kafka',
  'AWS Lambda',
  'Azure',
  'OpenStack'],
 'Storage': ['AWS S3',
  'MongoDB',
  'Cassandra',
  'MySQL',
  'PostgreSQL',
  'AWS DynamoDB',
  'Spring Data MongoDB',
  'AWS RDS',
  'MySQL/MariaDB',
  'Datadog',
  'Memcached'],
 'Languages': ['Java',
  'PHP',
  'SQL',
  'Bash',
  'Perl',
  'JavaScript',
  'Python',
  'C#',
  'Go'],
 'Frameworks': ['Ruby on Rails (RoR)',
  'AWS HA',
  '.NET',
  'Serverless Framework',
  'Selenium',
  'CodeIgniter',
  'Express.js'],
 'Other': ['Cisco',
  'Content Delivery Networks (CDN)',
  'Kubernetes Operations (Kops)',
  'Prometheus',
  'VMware ESXi',
  'Bash Scripting',
  'Scrum Master',
  'Infrastructure as Code',
  'Performance Tuning',
  'Serverless',
  'System Administration',
  'Linux System Administration',
  'Code Review'],
 'Libraries/APIs': ['Node.js',
  'Jenkins Pipeline',
  'jQuery',
  'React',
  'Selenium Grid'],
 'Tools': ['Jenkins',
  'Bitbucket',
  'GitHub',
  'AWS ECS',
  'AWS IAM',
  'Amazon CloudFront CDN',
  'Terraform',
  'AWS CloudFormation',
  'Git Flow',
  'Artifactory',
  'Nginx',
  'Grafana',
  'Zabbix',
  'Docker Compose',
  'AWS CLI',
  'AWS ECR',
  'Chef',
  'Jira',
  'Git',
  'Postfix',
  'MongoDB Shell',
  'Wowza',
  'Amazon SQS',
  'AWS SES',
  'Subversion (SVN)',
  'TeamCity',
  'Microsoft Visual Studio',
  'Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)',
  'VMware ESX',
  'Fluentd',
  'Sumo Logic',
  'Slack',
  'Apache ZooKeeper',
  'AWS Fargate',
  'Ansible',
  'ELK (Elastic Stack)',
  'Microsoft Team Foundation Server',
  'Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)']}
```

I want to grab ONLY the values and add these to a new column.

I've tried:

```
# convert dict values to str
for index, row in toptal["skills"].items():
    for key, val in row.items():
        row.update({key: str(val)})

# reverse dict keys and values
for index, row in toptal["skills"].items():
    inv_dict = {v: k for k, v in row.items()}

# map inv_dict to new column
toptal["skills_list"] = toptal["skills"].apply(
    lambda x: {k for k, v in inv_dict.items()}
)
```

The issue looks to be with the last list comprehension within the lambda function. How do I loop through all key, value pairs of the dictionary (within that row) to assign each value to that row? To get this output:

```
row 1: ['Agile Software Development','Scrum','DevOps', 'Serverless Architecture'], ['Kubernetes','Linux','Windows','Eclipse','PagerDuty','Apache2','Docker','AWS EC2','Amazon Web Services (AWS)','Sysdig','Apache Kafka','AWS Lambda','Azure','OpenStack'],['AWS S3','MongoDB','Cassandra','MySQL','PostgreSQL','AWS DynamoDB','Spring Data MongoDB','AWS RDS','MySQL/MariaDB','Datadog','Memcached']...
```

I've been able to append each list to a successive row but I want all lists to be contained within one row.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: To simply create a dataframe with these values, pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) should fix your problem ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html))

Comment: That actually creates a new row for each value in the dict, and I'm trying to keep those values contained to one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could try with `json_normalize`:

```
#dictionary given
d={'Paradigms': ['Agile Software Development', 'Scrum', 'DevOps', 'Serverless Architecture'], 'Platforms': ['Kubernetes', 'Linux', 'Windows', 'Eclipse', 'PagerDuty', 'Apache2', 'Docker', 'AWS EC2', 'Amazon Web Services (AWS)', 'Sysdig', 'Apache Kafka', 'AWS Lambda', 'Azure', 'OpenStack'], 'Storage': ['AWS S3', 'MongoDB', 'Cassandra', 'MySQL', 'PostgreSQL', 'AWS DynamoDB', 'Spring Data MongoDB', 'AWS RDS', 'MySQL/MariaDB', 'Datadog', 'Memcached'], 'Languages': ['Java', 'PHP', 'SQL', 'Bash', 'Perl', 'JavaScript', 'Python', 'C#', 'Go'], 'Frameworks': ['Ruby on Rails (RoR)', 'AWS HA', '.NET', 'Serverless Framework', 'Selenium', 'CodeIgniter', 'Express.js'], 'Other': ['Cisco', 'Content Delivery Networks (CDN)', 'Kubernetes Operations (Kops)', 'Prometheus', 'VMware ESXi', 'Bash Scripting', 'Scrum Master', 'Infrastructure as Code', 'Performance Tuning', 'Serverless', 'System Administration', 'Linux System Administration', 'Code Review'], 'Libraries/APIs': ['Node.js', 'Jenkins Pipeline', 'jQuery', 'React', 'Selenium Grid'], 'Tools': ['Jenkins', 'Bitbucket', 'GitHub', 'AWS ECS', 'AWS IAM', 'Amazon CloudFront CDN', 'Terraform', 'AWS CloudFormation', 'Git Flow', 'Artifactory', 'Nginx', 'Grafana', 'Zabbix', 'Docker Compose', 'AWS CLI', 'AWS ECR', 'Chef', 'Jira', 'Git', 'Postfix', 'MongoDB Shell', 'Wowza', 'Amazon SQS', 'AWS SES', 'Subversion (SVN)', 'TeamCity', 'Microsoft Visual Studio', 'Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)', 'VMware ESX', 'Fluentd', 'Sumo Logic', 'Slack', 'Apache ZooKeeper', 'AWS Fargate', 'Ansible', 'ELK (Elastic Stack)', 'Microsoft Team Foundation Server', 'Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)']}

#Create a dataframe with dictionaries like above

df=pd.DataFrame({'d':[d,d]})
print(df)
#                                                   d
#0  {'Paradigms': ['Agile Software Development', '...
#1  {'Paradigms': ['Agile Software Development', '...

#use json_normalize
print(pd.json_normalize(df['d']))
                                           Paradigms                                          Platforms                                            Storage                                          Languages                                         Frameworks                                              Other                                     Libraries/APIs                                              Tools
0  [Agile Software Development, Scrum, DevOps, Se...  [Kubernetes, Linux, Windows, Eclipse, PagerDut...  [AWS S3, MongoDB, Cassandra, MySQL, PostgreSQL...  [Java, PHP, SQL, Bash, Perl, JavaScript, Pytho...  [Ruby on Rails (RoR), AWS HA, .NET, Serverless...  [Cisco, Content Delivery Networks (CDN), Kuber...  [Node.js, Jenkins Pipeline, jQuery, React, Sel...  [Jenkins, Bitbucket, GitHub, AWS ECS, AWS IAM,...
1  [Agile Software Development, Scrum, DevOps, Se...  [Kubernetes, Linux, Windows, Eclipse, PagerDut...  [AWS S3, MongoDB, Cassandra, MySQL, PostgreSQL...  [Java, PHP, SQL, Bash, Perl, JavaScript, Pytho...  [Ruby on Rails (RoR), AWS HA, .NET, Serverless...  [Cisco, Content Delivery Networks (CDN), Kuber...  [Node.js, Jenkins Pipeline, jQuery, React, Sel...  [Jenkins, Bitbucket, GitHub, AWS ECS, AWS IAM,...
```

**Edit**: Use `.values()` to get only the values of the dictionary:

```
df['d']=df['d'].apply(lambda x: list(x.values()))
```

Comment: Each dictionary is contained with a row of a pandas df. How would I implement so as to loop through and apply json normalize to each row? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Could you add a sample of the original data?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eoefelein/talent/master/toptal_pulling_skill_dict_values.csv?token=ANECUYOOMDOJZ64MGOK6OB27HRJQ4

Comment: Let me know if you're not able to access!^

Comment: It gives "404 page not found" @Erin

Comment: So sorry, I made that repo public. Hopefully that fixes it!

Comment: @Erin, so you want that column 'skills' get "expanded" like I did with json_normalize, yes?

Comment: So this: ""{'Paradigms': ['Agile Software Development', 'Scrum', 'DevOps', 'Serverless Architecture'], 'Platforms': ['Kubernetes', 'Linux', 'Windows', 'Eclipse', 'PagerDuty', 'Apache2', 'Docker', 'AWS EC2', 'Amazon Web Services (AWS)', 'Sysdig', 'Apache Kafka', 'AWS Lambda', 'Azure', 'OpenStack'], ...  'Microsoft Team Foundation Server', 'Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)']}"" is one entry.

Comment: I want to pull the values from this dictionary and add them as a new column. I'm just having trouble iterating over the dataframe and then iterating over the dictionary to do this and keep getting the first dictionary's values returned for every column. So I want to exclude the keys, Paradigm, Platforms, Storage, etc and return only their values (which are stored as lists). I've tried make a separate list also, but what ends up happening is that each list gets appended to each row, whereas all the lists seen here should go in one row. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahhh, I think I get it, you mean, to get the only values (which are lists) stored in a list at "skill" column, yes?  @Erin

Comment: Exactly! And I'm not sure how to deal with iterating through the dataframe and through the values in a way as to contain the returned values within one row.